# IJCADの.Netで行列計算が行われない

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD 2018で.Net開発をしています。行列計算のメソッドが機能していないようなので質問させていただきます。再現コードはこちら。

```
[CommandMethod("test", CommandFlags.Session)]
public static void test()
{
    var d = new double[]
    {
        0.99359167957899042,-0.11302908595313337,0,316450.20558663277,
        0.11302908595313337, 0.99359167957899042, 0, 37145.293791644872,
        0,0,1,0,
        0,0,0,1
    };

    var mat  = new Matrix3d(d);
    Debug.Print(mat.CoordinateSystem3d.ToString());

    // CoordinateSystem3dが計算前のままになっている
    var mat2 = mat.Transpose();
    Debug.Print(mat2.CoordinateSystem3d.ToString());
}
```

Matrix3d.Transpose()の実行結果でMatrix3d.CoordinateSystem3dの値が計算前のままになっているのですが、この問題を回避するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

Comment: 過去、あなたの質問への回答が一切承認されていません。解決済みであれば、承認をお願いします。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

お疲れさまです。
このAPIは不具合のようですね。

解決方法としては自前で以下のような手続きを行えば解決できます。

計算前行列---------------------------------
Origin = (14,24,34),
Xaxis  = (11,21,31),
Yaxis  = (12,22,32),
Zaxis  = (13,23,33)

計算後行列---------------------------------
Origin = (41,43,43),
Xaxis  = (11,12,13),
Yaxis  = (21,22,23),
Zaxis  = (31,32,33))